# Django testing - wait for subprocess to be ready

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, subprocess, pouchdb

I'm using pouchdb-server to create an in-memory database to run my test against with the following code:

```
class CouchdbTestCase(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.proc = subprocess.Popen('pouchdb-server --in-memory', shell=True)
        time.sleep(1)

    def tearDown(self):
        process = psutil.Process(self.proc.pid)
        for proc in process.children(recursive=True):
            proc.kill()
        process.kill()
```

the time.sleep(1) is there as otherwise the tests are ran before the in-memory server is ready

Is there a more graceful way to ensure the server is ready without having to do such a long wait?

edit:
I've receive comment that shell=True may not be necessary. Please note that this code runs on windows and does not work if it's removed.

Comment: Use `shell=True` only when necessary (it isn’t here).

Comment: @DavisHerring actually, if `shell=True` is not there I get the following error: `FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified`

Comment: You do have to switch to `['program','argument',...]` when not using `shell`.  But that’s good practice and easily supports computed arguments with no quoting needed.